# Munin does not produce any output

Tags: centos, munin

To setup munin I did the following:

```
yum install munin munin-node -y
```

Then set the

```
htmldir /var/www/virtualhosts/ssl.foo.com/bar

[foo.com]
    address 127.0.0.1
    use_node_name yes
```

In `/etc/munin/munin.conf`. I kept the user for munin root. Restarted munin (`/etc/init.d/munin-node restart`).

Munin is runing:

```
[root@server ~]# ps aux | grep munin
root     41077  0.1  0.0 143236  8508 ?        Ss   10:48   0:00 /usr/sbin/munin-node
root     41432  0.0  0.0 103268   828 pts/0    S+   10:48   0:00 grep munin

[root@server ~]# netstat -anp | grep munin-node
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4949                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      41077/munin-node
```

However, there is nothing populated in the `htmldir`. What could have gone wrong?

Note:

- SElinux is disabled
- `/var/log/munin/munin-node.log` does not mention any errors
- munin comes from epel repo

All munin related packages:

```
[root@server ~]# yum list installed | grep munin
munin.noarch                        1.4.7-5.el6                        @epel    
munin-common.noarch                 1.4.7-5.el6                        @epel    
munin-node.noarch                   1.4.7-5.el6                        @epel
```

Answer (score 1):

## /etc/init.d/munin-node restart and run munin-update cmd as munin user account where your server is configured this will let u know that munin server is communicating with munin-node..

and try this #telnet foo.example.com 4949 and If the plugin does run with munin-run but not through telnet, you probably have a PATH problem and also Check that the plugin's field name have the .value directive on each field name

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you changed it or not, but does the [foo.com] hostname match both in your munin.conf file *and* your munin-node.conf file? that stopped munin from working for me if I recall correctly.